For Maui.NET, how can I get Shell.FlyoutContent to work on iOS
When I run the following Maui.NET xaml code on Android, and click the hamburger button, I see a green flyout menu with the text "hello".
When I try it on iOS I get a blank flyout.
How can I fix this?
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Title="MauiApp2">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    
    <Shell.FlyoutContent>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="ForestGreen">
            <Label Text="hello"/>
        </Frame>
    </Shell.FlyoutContent>
</Shell>



What is your .NET MAUI version? .NET7 or .NET8?

What kind of effect are you trying to achieve? It is true that on iOS platform, after clicked the burger icon, it showed a blank space, but in android platform, I got a green background covered with flyout and no "hello" text was shown, which is not beautiful from the design point of view. Can you describe in detail what you want to achieve? Or you can provide your screen shoot of the view on android platform.

I'm using .net 8. I have a whole content page I'm porting from xamarin with buttons, tabs, menu items, grids and frames... etc. In xamarin the flyout content could be represented by a contentpage, but this is not working in Maui, so I tried to reduce the problem to its most basic elements for testing, hence the green background and label, but it is still not working. To reproduce this you can just create a brand new Maui app and paste in the above xaml

@jho you want to put all green or just like the photo?

I've found the solution to the problem, it's quite simple. Simply wrap the content in a ContentView.
Thanks Shuowen and Giorgio for your replies. You helped push me towards the final answer :)
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp2.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    Title="MauiApp2">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    
    <Shell.FlyoutContent>
        <ContentView>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="ForestGreen">
                <Label Text="hello"/>
            </Frame>
        </ContentView>
    </Shell.FlyoutContent>
</Shell>


What has worked for me, I give you the example with the header is:
Create a xaml that is StackLayout.
    <StackLayout xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="x.Views.Dashboard.FlyoutHeaderControl"
             Padding="10"
             BackgroundColor="#44185f">
    <Label>
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span x:Name="lblUserFullName" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
    <Label x:Name="lblEmail" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Italic" TextColor="White"/>
</StackLayout>

I have it on the App.xaml.cs but where you need it put this:
 AppShell.Current.FlyoutHeader = new FlyoutHeaderControl();

It may work for you by making a FlyoutContent.
